# Creating a cocoapod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I have developed a small library and I want to create a Cocoapod for it. the problem is whenever I run `script pod spec lint xxx.podspec --verbose --no-clean --use-libraries` I got

> - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Pods written in Swift can only be integrated as frameworks; add `use_frameworks!` to your Podfile or target to opt into using it. The Swift Pod being used is: Socialite) during validation.

I am making the lib using `pod lib create xxx`

Comment: I never used pod lib create for swift pods. Refer to Alamofire's setup, that should be the good example of how a swift pod should be: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `--use-libraries` with a Swift pod, as they have to be frameworks. If you remove that - it will run the linter.

Comment: If I remove `--use-libraries` the I will git the following : 

`- ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (The 'Pods' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/private/var/folders/wx/r2p4ty_n0js19g0vc88p589w0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/Fabric/Fabric.framework, /private/var/folders/wx/r2p4ty_n0js19g0vc88p589w0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/TwitterCore/TwitterCore.framework, and /private/var/folders/wx/r2p4ty_n0js19g0vc88p589w0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Lint/Pods/TwitterKit/TwitterKit.framework)) during validation.
`

Comment: if I remove 's.dependency 'TwitterCore'
s.dependency 'TwitterKit'
s.dependency 'Fabric'' the .podspec will  pass the validation.

Comment: Yeah, Twitter need to release a dynamic framework version of their library. CocoaPods cannot link transitive static dependencies I'm afraid.